# How do I log to an additional log provider in a Azure Function 2.0

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, serverless

We want to log to a log provider (Seq) in our functions in addition to Application Insights.

We are having a hard time to understand how to set this up in our extension of FunctionsStartup, where we set up other dependencies.

The way we see it this can be resolved in (at least) two ways.

1) Bootstrap our function app with the default logger (which logs to App Insights) *in addition* to our custom logger (A Serilog logger which is setup with a sink to Seq)

2) Do a runtime Dependency Injection resolve of ILogger and perform the logging to App Insights on this one *in addition* to logging to Seq. Then we could have a Singleton ICompanyLogger which logs to both.

Does anyone know how to do a runtime DI resolve in a function and/or how to setup multiple sinks in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger ?

Comment: All logging providers are added the same way. Application Insights isn't a default, it has to be added to the logging providers too. This sounds more like a question about your code than logging itself. What does your code look like? Did you check [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configuration) ?

Comment: You can use [Seq.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/datalust/seq-extensions-logging) package to integrade Seq with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. Once you add the package all you need to do is add `logging.AddSeq("http://localhost:5341");` in `ConfigureLogging`

Comment: I see that the documentation on how `FunctionsStartup` is scarce, the ... paragraph about [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#logging-services) isn't helpful  and the [class itself](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/blob/master/src/Extensions/DependencyInjection/FunctionsStartup.cs) is little more than a call to `IWebJobsBuilder.Services`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Followup question: Do you know if we can get ahold of the actual ILogger while we invoke our FunctionsStartup subclass where we bootstrap the function. In that way we could inject it into a the dependencies we set up (we have a service client which does logging)

Answer (score 3):

To actually enable logging in a Azure Function the following must be added to host.json :

```
{
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Warning"
        }
    }
}
```

When not setting this default level, a log invocation results in no logging (IMO this should be defaulting to at least Error, when the "default" is not set in configuration)

Comment: So simple, but that's what I'd been missing - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to inject the logger of your choosing in the latest version.

Here is how to setup the DI, its almost exactly the same as .Net Core.

https://ikethe.dev/azure-functions-adds-dependency-injection/

Once your startup class is created, just add what you need to the functions constructor.